# converting a function that accepts closures to accept functions

Tags: swift, closures

I have a function that accepts a closure as an argument

```
public func createSelector<Input: Hashable, Output, A>(_ selectorA: @escaping (Input) -> A, _ combine: @escaping (A) -> Output) -> (Input) -> Output {
    return memoize({ combine(selectorA($0)) })
}
```

A use case is something like this

```
let getStore = { (store: AppState?) -> FeedState? in store?.feed }

let getFeedItems = createSelector(getStore) { (state: FeedState?) -> [Post] in state?.posts ?? [] }
```

This is used to select a piece of state from a `ReSwift` store and return results after running a `memoize` function.

Xcode seems to struggle with auto complete when using this closure pattern

[image]

When I expect it to be able to show props as follows

[image]

It was suggested to me that writing my closures as functions will prevent this issue.

As such, I am trying to convert the above function to work with functions to see if this helps.

I am confused how the above pattern can be refactored to support functions instead and would appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Edit:

This is an example attempt:

```
func getStoreFunc(_ state: AppState?) -> FeedState? {
    return state?.feed
}

func getFeedItemsFunc(_ fn: @escaping (AppState?) -> FeedState?) -> [Post] {

    return createSelector(fn, { (state: FeedState?) -> [Post] in
        return state?.posts ?? []
    })
}
```

However this produces and error of

> Cannot convert return expression of type '(AppState?) -> [Post]' to
>   return type '[Post]'

on my `getFeedItemsFunc`

Comment: I would advise against using the term `selector`, which is a term of art in ObjC/Swift with a very particular meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createSelector(_:_:)` function takes two closures. However, Swift lets you pass functions in place of closures so long as the types match.

In your code, you declared one closure beforehand (`getStore`) and wrote the other one using trailing closure syntax when you called the `createSelector(_:_:)` method. However, functions can't be declared using this syntax. So I created a function called `getPostsFunc(_:)` that replaces your second closure.

```swift
// corresponds to:
//let getStore = { (store: AppState?) -> FeedState? in store?.feed }
func getStoreFunc(_ state: AppState?) -> FeedState? {
    return state?.feed
}

//corresponds to:
//{ (state: FeedState?) -> [Post] in state?.posts ?? [] }
func getPostsFunc(_ state: FeedState?) -> [Post] {
    return state?.posts ?? []
}

//This is the same as your `getFeedItems`
let getFeedItems = createSelector(getStoreFunc, getPostsFunc)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I really appreciate that, it's helped a bunch :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!